# Select a range on an X axis using WPF toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm using the charts that come with wpf toolkit, specifically the area, scatter, and line Series. I managed to display data, but I need to select a range of data in that chart, something like [this](http://ec2-23-22-16-239.compute-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/zoom-line-select-date-range.png).

Note that is not intented to zoom, only selection.

I have two approaches:

1. reproduce that behaviour exactly. That is, start dragging in the chart and when you finish dragging keep the selection.
2. Click in one point to select it, the property isSelectionEnabled must be set to true, and then click on another point, and to give the user visual feedback, paint that chunk of the area in another color.

The code of my UserControl referring to the chart:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="myData>
        <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries 
            Name="m_colserHistogram" 
            Title="nombre propiedad" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" 
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}" 
            IsSelectionEnabled="True"
            IsManipulationEnabled="True" IsHitTestVisible="True">

            <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" Interval="{Binding ChartingInterval}"  Minimum="0" Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="False" />
            </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.DependentRangeAxis>

            <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.IndependentAxis>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" Interval="{Binding ChartingInterval}"  Minimum="0" Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True" />
            </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.IndependentAxis>

        </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries>

    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour easily?

PD: The data is loaded from an XML.
If it's not easy to reproduce, any library / controls / whatever to get this functionality? Free and open source preferred.

Thanks in advance, and if more detail is needed, ask for it.